# how to add new monetary filed to invoice form in Odoo 9?

Tags: odoo-9, invoice

I'm learning to customize again Odoo 9 system. Due to some characteristics of my own business I have to change some points in the account invoice template. I have created a new monetary filed with name total_residual and its value is computed by the function show bellow:

```
@api.multi
def _compute_all_residual(self):
    for invoice in self:
        invs = self.search([('state', '=', 'open'), ('partner_id', '=', invoice.partner_id.id)])
        out_invoice = 0
        in_invoice = 0
        out_refund = 0
        in_refund = 0
        for inv in invs:
            if inv.type == 'out_invoice':
                out_invoice += inv.residual
            if inv.type == 'in_invoice':
                in_invoice += inv.residual
            if inv.type == 'out_refund':
                out_refund += inv.residual
            if inv.type == 'in_refund':
                in_refund += inv.residual
        invoice.total_residual = out_invoice + in_refund - in_invoice - out_refund
```

now I would like to add a new field monetary field (old_residual) with value is total residual exclude the amount of current invoice. what is the right function to add on the module? and how come I show the value of old_residual to qweb report? thank for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create New Monetary field and Re-write above method:

```
@api.multi
def _compute_all_residual(self):
for invoice in self:
    invs = self.search([('state', '=', 'open'), ('partner_id', '=', invoice.partner_id.id)])
    out_invoice = 0
    in_invoice = 0
    out_refund = 0
    in_refund = 0
    for inv in invs:
        if inv.type == 'out_invoice':
            out_invoice += inv.residual
        if inv.type == 'in_invoice':
            in_invoice += inv.residual
        if inv.type == 'out_refund':
            out_refund += inv.residual
        if inv.type == 'in_refund':
            in_refund += inv.residual
    invoice.total_residual = out_invoice + in_refund - in_invoice - out_refund
    invoice.old_residual = out_invoice + in_refund - in_invoice - out_refund - invoice.amount_total

# Define new field
old_residual = fields.Monetary(string='Amount Due', compute='_compute_all_residual', store=True)
```

To add above field in qweb report you need to inherit qweb template and add this field in it.

Try it with the following code in your "views/report_invoice.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_invoice_document_custom" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
            <xpath expr="//tr[@class='border-black']" position="after">
                <!-- Your Code --->
                <tr class="border-black">
                    <td><strong>Old Residual</strong></td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                         <span t-field="o.old_residual" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Add the report in youre "**openerp**.py" file in the data.

```
'data': ['views/report_invoice.xml',],
```

Comment: I will try to finished follow your code form. Thank you for helping me. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hello Mr. Malani i have created the new field but the filed only show out at the invoice form but the value seem isn't caculated at all, and allways show the amount = 0.00 đ. Did i forgot any step?